# Node.JS File Logging

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to log stuf into a file, but like with my own logs. I tried to create a Array and just stuff all the logs into it as a own string element and each 10 seconds, it appends the stuff to the file. It actually works fine BUT i have the problem that some logs get written twice. I try to asyncrously start writing the logs to the file and then clear the array to make it ready for new logs. Unfortunately, that creates clones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is amazing NPMS for that's you need to save your logs in a `.log` file.
I use log4js.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me that logger, I replaced everything and it worked out great because my logging was very stupid.

Comment: I'm very happy to help.